# Build visual studio solution using msbuild from c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I want to build my solution file from other c# code using msbuid I have tried

```
var msbuild_path = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe";
var solution_path = @"D:\Sumit\WorkingCopy\Final\Final.sln";            
Process.Start(msbuild_path + " " + solution_path);
```

but this one throws an error Please help me out!!

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx ,  the Process.Start method takes two arguments:

```
public static Process Start(string fileName, string arguments)
```

So you should change your code to

```
Process.Start(msbuild_path, solution_path);
```

What you were doing before was actually trying to run a file named "*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe(**space**)D:\Sumit\WorkingCopy\Final\Final.sln*", but no such file exists with that name. The msbuild.exe may exist, but "*msbuild.exe D:\Sumit...\Final.sln*" is not the filename you meant to pass as the command filename. Also, the argument string was empty, so the system assumed you did not want to pass any arguments to "msbuild.exe D:\Sumit...\Final.sln". But the error message was because the two filenames were mashed into one filename.

Windows allows filenames to contain embedded spaces, which frequently causes problems in dealing with command-line arguments.